# Attacking queen problem (variation of N queen)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am trying to solve for an attacking queens problem (which is a variation of the N-Queens problem): using two parameters, where N > 3 and k ≥ 0, to place on an N × N board a maximum number of Queens such that each of them attacks exactly k other Queens. Hence, when k = 0, the problem reduces to the standard N-Queens problem.

I have tried modifying the backtracking algorithm to solve this, where I left the queen there instead of moving the queen away when it is in a position of being attacked (not safe position), however the algorithm doesn't seem to work out when i try it.

I can't figure out which part of my algorithm is wrong.

I have tried modifying the backtracking algorithm:
This is my attempt so far:

```
void printSolution(int board[N][N])
{
    static int k = 1;
    printf("%d-\n",k++);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %d ", board[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

bool isSafe(int board[N][N], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;
 
    /* Check this row on left side */
    for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
        if (board[row][i])
            return false;
 
    /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
    for (i=row, j=col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;
 
    /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
    for (i=row, j=col; j>=0 && i<N; i++, j--)
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;
 
    return true;
}

/* A recursive utility function to solve N
Queen problem */
bool solveNQUtil(int board[N][N], int col)
{
    /* base case: If all queens are placed
    then return true */
    if (col == N)
    {
        printSolution(board);
        return true;
    }
 
    /* Consider this column and try placing
    this queen in all rows one by one */
    bool res = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        /* Check if queen can be placed on
        board[i][col] */
        if ( !isSafe(board, i, col) ) // meaning if Dangerous, place queen
        {
            /* Place this queen in board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 1;
 
            // Make result true if any placement
            // is possible
            res = solveNQUtil(board, col + 1) || res;
 
            /* If placing queen in board[i][col]
            doesn't lead to a solution, then
            remove queen from board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 0; // BACKTRACK
        }
    }
 
    /* If queen can not be place in any row in
        this column col then return false */
    return res;
}

void solveNQ()
{
    int board[N][N];
    memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
 
    if (solveNQUtil(board, 0) == false)
    {
        printf("Solution does not exist");
        return ;
    }
 
    return ;
}
 
// driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    solveNQ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know as well where your algorithm is wrong. However, if I was you, I would make a sample - with a (not too large) initial setup and solve this by hand (or on paper). Then I would use the debugger to execute the program step by step watching if it does reasonable calculations. Finally, I should find out either the wrong piece in the code or realize that my algorithm might be wrong.

Comment: This solution is completely wrong given the problem statement. The backtracking only checks for "safe" positions, which works for the case `k=0` but fails immediately for any case `k>0`. For `k>0` you must track how many times each queen attacks other queens.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you're talking about is hard to solve in general (maybe someone knows if it is NP hard?).

The code you provided is not enough to tell what's wrong with your algorithm (except that you don't count the attacking queens in `isSafe`).

Let's first look at the problem, where you don't want exactly k attacks, but at most k attacks.
To achieve that, you can just modify the normal n-queen backtracking algorithm so that you don't check if a square is attacked, but if it is attacked by less than k other queens.
In addition, you need to check if the new queen attacks another queen that already was attacked by k others.
So just modify your `isSafe` function to count how many queens are attacked from that square and also check it for every queen is attack from that square (or just always check the whole board, slower, but simple).

Your `board` array is of type `int[][]`, so maybe what you tried is to keep track of how often these squares are attacked, that's totally fine, too and actually makes it easier to check. But you then have to update it properly, and that may be hard, when you remove queens.

Now to your actual problem:
In the previous case, you could immediately check if the board you end up with after you placed a new queen, can be valid (because you just not place queens when that violate the maximal attack count in some way).
In the exact case, you don't know that, because you don't know if you end up with exactly `k` queens attacking it. You don't know if you will be able to place more queens in a valid way to exactly match the attack count.

However, that does not mean, it it not possible, the algorithm is just not as inefficient as the normal previous problem.

A solutuion might look like this:

```
bool is_valid(board, attacks); // checks if every queen is attacked by at most "attacks" other queens
bool is_valid_exact(board, attacks); // checks if every queen is attacked by exactly "attacks" other queens

bool n_queens_attack_exact(bool board[N][N], int attacks, int pos, int depths){
  // board always is valid for at most k attacks
  if(depths <= 0) {
    // when all queens are placed, check if the solution is also valid for exactly k attacks
    if(is_valid_exact(board, attacks)) {
      printSolution(board);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  bool success = false;
  // i just use i from 0 to N+N nstad of i and j from 0 to N, because its easy to cout
  for(int i = pos; i < N*N; ++i){
    // place new queen
    board[i%N][i/N] = true;
    // if there now is a queen with more than k attacks, we dont' need to continue
    if (is_valid(board, attacks))
      success = n_queens_attack_exact(board, attacks, i + 1, depths-1);
    // remove queen bofore trying the next square
    board[i%N][i/N] = false;
    // stop if successful
    if (success)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// try to place 11 queens (best possible) on a 5x5 grid with k = 4
bool board[5][5]; // actually, you should set everything to false
n_queens_attack_exact(board, 4, 0, 11);
```

Output:

```
 0  1  1  1  0 
 1  0  0  0  1 
 1  0  0  0  0 
 1  0  0  0  1 
 0  1  1  1  0
```

To find the best solution possible just iterate over the number of queens you try to place.

You need to be careful when you stop trying.
For example it is not possible for k=1 to place any odd number of queens in a valid combination (but you don't want to stop trying immediately, just because placing a single queen was not working). I am not sure if the same may happen in other cases.

With this example, you can see, that it is not possible, to solve the at-most case first and the test if the solutions are valid in the exact case, because with at most `k=4` attacks, there is a better solution with 12 queens:

```
 1  1  1  1  1 
 1  0  0  0  0 
 1  0  0  0  0 
 1  0  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  1  1
```

Btw.: there are only solutions for `k < 5`, because there must be one or more left most queens and the first of them can only attack in 4 directions (not left at all and not directly up).